# Date input in HTML5: Highlight each Monday using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date, datepicker, calendar

I'm working on a website that uses the `<input type=”date”>` to show a datepicker through the browser’s native widget. I need that the users cannot book on Mondays because the service is closed. I know that I can’t prevent selection of weekends or disallow Mondays purely through markup. Instead, I used the HTML5 validation API, and the native JavaScript Date object to notify the users when they have picked a Monday.

I also would like to higlight with a different color each Monday to tell the users before they submit a date that Monday is not permitted.

I need to use pure Javascript only.

Any suggestion to do that?

```js
var date = document.querySelector('[type=date]');

function noMondays(e){

    var day = new Date( e.target.value ).getUTCDay();

    // Days in JS range from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday

    if( day == 1 ){

        e.target.setCustomValidity('OH NOES! We hate Mondays! Please pick any day but Monday.')
      

    } else {

        e.target.setCustomValidity('');

    }

}

date.addEventListener('input',noMondays);
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="date"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You can't access date native widget via javascript. You'll have to create your own calendar popup for that.

Comment: The code I posted works, if you try to select Monday and then submit you can see the notification. I have only to implement the code to highlight every Mondays.

Comment: your code works for the input field, not the widget that shows when calendar icon clicked.

Comment: Yes, that's true. No way.